# Inferior-Shell Live Print Output

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm using `inferior-shell:run` to launch a long-running task which can routinely fail (it's a build validation routine).

My main issue is that I could not find a way of seeing the "live" output of the launched activity.

The reason why I'd like a live-feed is because I could not see the output if an error happened; I looked into the `ON-ERROR:` key, but it yielded little more than saying that there was an exit code of 1. This makes sense, as it seems like this key is a callback to take some kind of recovery action. However, if my task fails, I'd also like to know why it failed, and that's hidden in the output of the command, which does not seem to be accessible.

I tried calling `RUN` like this:

```
(inferior-shell:run
    (pod-command file)        ; this generates a string shell
                              ;   command from the arg FILE
    :on-error #'print         ; tells me that the exit code was 1 
    :output *standard-output* ; default, if I understand correctly
    :interactive t)           ; this was a shot in the dark
```

Even in the success case, it would still be nice to see output as it's being produced (instead of at the end) but that's just a nice-to-have.

I'm only just beginning to learn Lisp, so I apologize if I missed something obvious.

I'm loading `inferior-shell` with `quickload` in `sbcl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation string of `inferior-shell:run`.  You can set both `output` and `error-output` to `:string`, which means that they will be the first and second return value, respectively.  The third return value is the exit code.  You can bind these values with `multiple-value-bind`.  If `:on-error` is `nil`, no error will be signalled in the case of a non-zero exit code.

Example:

```
CL-USER> (inferior-shell:run "git status"
                             :on-error nil
                             :error-output :string
                             :output :string)
""
"fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
"
128
```

Comment: I think he wants something different: live output, output of the command while it is running.

Comment: I interpreted that part as "nice to have" (third to last paragraph). It is usually not necessary for analyzing the output of a build.

Comment: I'm sorry, I accidentally asked two questions in one and didn't update the title to reflect the priority. I will test the `error-output` key and then accept the answer if that works!

Comment: I tried `:error-output :string` and `error-output *standard-output*` but neither worked; I still just get `#<UIOP/RUN-PROGRAM:SUBPROCESS-ERROR {10027BB0F3}> `. However, with your example I did get the expected result. I suppose I should accept your answer since it's correct; it just doesn't solve my particular error case.

Comment: Nope, I take that back, mistake on my part. Perfect solution, thank you so much! And thank you for the `multiple-value-bind` hint; I've run into multiple returns before and didn't find a great solution for handling them.